# Charge % less than 100% even overnight?

Tags: charging, iphone

When I charge my iPhone 4s it reaches 100%. But often, in the morning, it is as low as 95% and most of the time it shows less than 100%. If I unplug it and then plug it in again it quickly reaches 100% again. How to fix? Not a problem?

Comment: I appreciate the links to proper battery use, but my iPod Touch never did this so I think it is an iPhone or iOS 5 issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to completely unload your iPhone. Let it go to 0 % (and shut down from itself), then plug it and let it charge completely. It should fix your problem.

See this articles from Apple for more information:

- http://www.apple.com/batteries/iphone.html
- http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1476

The gists you need:

> For proper maintenance of a lithium-based battery, it’s important to keep the electrons in it moving occasionally. Be sure to **go through at least one charge cycle per month (charging the battery to 100% and then completely running it down)**.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this on my 4s too. Try this: keep the phone plugged into its charger, wake it up and let it sit for a bit awake. It should pop up to 100% pretty quickly.

I'm guessing, but I don't know for sure, that this is yet another bug in the battery/charging routines in iOS 5.0.1 and will get fixed at some point.

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone 4s has a **Li-ion** battery.

> Li-ion cannot absorb overcharge, and when fully charged the charge
>   current must be cut off. A continuous trickle charge would cause
>   plating of metallic lithium, and this could compromise safety.

It's important to know that **once the charging process is completed, the battery is never actually full**. There's always a bit of 'space' left. If you keep reconnecting your phone and charging it again for several times, you can increase the charge. This is called **bump charging**.

I would assume that Apple engineers changed the calcuation for the saturation of charge. The way the iPhone 4s behaves now is what the Nexus S has had already:

> Once the battery is 'full' (=current cut off) the saturation
>   is recalculated to represent the actual charge.

I'm sure Apple wanted to show the 100% in the past in order to mute customer worries. **However, this 'new' behavior is totally normal and more realistic.**

For more infos about Li-ion battery, and measuring charge saturation see this link.
http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries